# Commerce Price Table: What would cause sporadic zeroing of prices when adding to cart?

Tags: commerce, rules

I'm having an issue where the prices in the price tables are sometimes being applied when adding items to the cart, and later, other items are set to zero when added to the cart. First off, I must mention that I am working with products that have 3 price tables, and each price table has 4 price breaks. I wasn't exactly clear on if/why support for multiple tables was or wasn't possible, but I am worried that this might be the culprit. If it's not safe to have multiple price tables for a product, please let me know right away!

Other details: Each of the 3 price tables for a product is for a different user role. I use field permissions on a multipage view to make this possible. What may make it complicated is that not every product has a price for each role. That is to say, not all products are available to all roles. To combat this, I added a filter to only show items where the price is not $0.

I'm very deeply entrenched in this module, as I have several commerce feeds going and thus have spent many hours formatting the incoming data in the CSV files, so Commerce Pricelist would not be a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, something is wrong somewhere when the rules are firing to apply pricing. [Read up on debugging rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1593278) and you'll likely find your problem.

One thing you may want to consider is just writing your own custom logic and then creating a new rule to call your custom logic, bypassing the logic of Commerce Price Table. You'll likely need to really spend your time adding your logic to `commerce_price_table_get_amount_qty` since that's where the actual field and price get determined.